# Long Exposure Photo vs. Video

Tags: post-processing, exposure, video, long-exposure, image-processing

If I want to make some cool photos with long exposure times but not having a good camera that allows me to define the time, can I get the same result recording a video and make the superposition of its several frames in my computer?

Answer (score 1):

Video has a much MUCH lower resolution than photos.  You can however do photo stacking and use a device called an intervalometer (assuming your camera has a remote port).